# Разнести метки с одинаковыми координатами

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Случается, что геокодер возвращает абсолютно одинаковые координаты для двух разных адресов (где-нибудь в пригороде, например). В этом случае, одна метка рисуется строго поверх другой и их надо "растаскивать" мышкой, а до этого, еще и понять что их там две. Выход видится такой: для каждого элемента массива меток искать дубликаты. Если дубли найдены — добавлять в координаты дублей небольшое смещение. Но после этого надо будет опять проверять на дубли (хотя бы только те элементы, которые принудительно смещались). Нет ли решения поизящнее (кроме кластеризатора)?

P.S.: необходимость двигать метки мышкой хоть и неприятна, но несмертельна. Но я планирую миграцию на `*ObjectManager`, а он таскание меток не поддерживает.

Comment: Чем вам кластеризатор не угодил? Кроме того дубликат - понятие относительное. То, что на одном масштабе очень далеко, в другом - одно и то же место. Как вариант - напишите свой кластеризатор

Comment: Когда геокодер не находит точных адресов, он ставит все метки точнехонько в одну точку. Например, номера домов в каком-нить селе он может не знать, да и даже улиц. Он их тогда поставит все где-нибудь в центре поселка. Кластеризатор данной проблемы не решит, разве что в режиме "по щелчку отображать балун кластеризатора, в котором уже есть ссылки на балуны отдельных меток". В моей задаче не подходит: метки одним своим видом несут две единицы информации: короткий текст и цвет. В кластер объедини -- какой текст писать? Какой цвет ставить? Плюс нужен будет еще дизайн для кластеризаторского балуна.

Comment: Вы когда отвечаете на комментарий, указывайте адресата - @ник Я случайно вернулся к этому вопросу. Я поэтому и говорил про "свой кластеризатор". Который не будет делать общую метку, а например распределять их равномерно по окружности фиксированного размера в масштабе экрана, а не местности

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть как устроен имеющийся кластеризатор - подключите карты с параметром `&mode=debug`

Comment: Насчет подписей не знаю, как решить проблему, а вот с цветом вполне себе - можно рисовать разноцветные метки-диаграммы кластера https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_pie_chart

Comment: @tutankhamun лучше в масштабе местности. Тогда они будут в виде иконки кластера изначально (с цветными секторами и тп; в общем там в дефолтном кластеризаторе и так хорошо), но при щелчке на кластеризатор — масштаб сильно увеличится и метки будут разнесены  вокруг пары домов.

Получается, что свой кластеризатор не нужен, а нужно просто метки сразу ставить чуть разнесенными (географически). У меня сейчас сделано разнесение "по линии", что не очень красиво/удобно. Идея с окружностью очень нравится, только радиус должен быть не константным, а зависеть от кол-ва меток в одной точке.

Comment: @tutankhamun но тут еще проблема такого характера: есть, допустим, два соседних дома (две точки с точными координатами), в каждом по несколько меток. Я собираю метки с дублирующимися координатами в две коллекции и в каждой из этих коллекций правлю координаты чтобы они немножечко расходились. До этог момента понятно. Но вот может оказаться что метка, отодвинутая вправо от центра левого дома может наложиться, теперь, на метку, отодвинутую влево от правого дома. Есть какие-то идеи как это можно предотвратить?

Comment: @Vladimir если существует такая вероятность, то по-хорошему метки для таких домов должны оказаться в одном кластере. Если это недопустимо по логике работы приложения, то вопрос становится сложнее. Давайте продолжим разговор в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72904/503758)